# What to do when the storage service is down while using Spring Session?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-redis, spring-session

As is described in the title. If the remote storage service is down, every request ganna throw 500 error. I don't know how to handle such exception nor the way to switch back to memory session storage durning the runingtime.

And it's weird that not much people is asking this question.

Solutions for:
(1) exception handler for session storage unavailable; or
(2) switch the session back during the runtime.